# I am trying to be able to take an uploaded image and make it the background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code isn't working and I cannot figure out why, I am trying to be able to take an uploaded image and make it the background image, without using a database. Please help! I work with HTML and CSS most often, but am trying the jquery code listed here to do what I am looking for.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Seamless Trial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        img {
            padding:1px;
            border:1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
            width:100px;
            }
        article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
                // Copyright 2001 by www.CodeBelly.com Please do *not* remove this notice.

            var backImage = new Array(); // don't change this

                // Enter the image filenames you wish to use. Follow the pattern to use more images.  
                // The number in the brackets [] is the number you number in the brackets [] is the number you
                // will use in the function call to pick each image.
                // Note how backImage[0] = "" -- which would set the page to *no* background image.

            backImage[0] = "#";
            backImage[0].id = "blah";  
            backImage[1] = "#";
            backImage[1].id = "blah";  
            backImage[2] = "black-rough-leather.jpg";
            backImage[3] = "newspapers.jpg";
            backImage[4] = "seamless-fuzzy-leopard.jpg";

                // ----Do not edit below this line.---

            function changeBGImage(whichImage){
                if (document.body){
                document.body.background = backImage[whichImage];}
            }

        //-->
        <!-- input thingy   
            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                    };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
        // end input thingy --!>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /><br><br>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(1)"><img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /></a>

    <a href="javascript:changeBGImage(2)"><img src="black-rough-leather.jpg"></a><br><br>
    <a href="javascript:changeBGImage(3)"><img src="newspapers.jpg"></a><br><br>
    <a href="javascript:changeBGImage(4)"><img src="seamless-fuzzy-leopard.jpg"></a><br><br>
    <a href="javascript:changeBGImage(5)"><img src=""></a><br><br>

</body>
```

Comment: what error you are getting in browser console?

Comment: I am not getting an error specifically, it just is not doing what I want it to do. (by which I mean being able to make the uploaded image into a repeated background image, either automatically on upload or on clicking the image after upload.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the body background, you should do the following.

```
 document.body.style.background = "url('" + backImage[whichImage] + "')";
```

Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/k463Ljzg/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!